# Who validates the OpenId Connect id_token? The Resource Server (API) or the Client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The question is basically in the title. I understand that the key to an appartment (the access_token to an API) does not really identify the one who uses it.

But how is the id_token any different? What additional security measures does it have?

And most importantly - who validates it? The Resoruce Server (API) on each request? And how would it do this? In my example the RS would be a Dotnet Core Api. Are there libraries or middleware to do this?

Or is it not even the Resource Server who validates it but the Client after receiving it from the Authorization Server (Idp)?

Comment: have you looked into bearer tokens https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750 ?